# Regex to match from multiple strings, retaining the order

Tags: python-3.x, regex

While trying to match multiple strings, the order seems to not amtter whereas the re documentation says otherwise. I want to look for the first match of the string in the regex pattern and then chop off the part before that string. The idea is to anonymize the company reference. Here's what I tried:

```
test_string = "Acme Corporation Inc. , together with its subsidiaries, produces and sells bauxite, alumina, and aluminum products in the United States, Spain, Australia, Brazil, Canada, and internationally. The company operates through three segments: Bauxite, Alumina, and Aluminum. It engages in bauxite mining operations; and processes bauxite into alumina and sells bauxite to customers who process it into industrial chemical products. The company is also involved in the aluminum smelting, casting, and rolling businesses; and the production of aluminum sheets primarily sold directly to customers in the packaging market for the production of aluminum cans. In addition, it owns hydro and coal generation assets that produce and sell electricity to the wholesale market to traders, large industrial consumers, distribution companies, and other generation companies. The company was formerly known as Acme Upstream Corporation and changed its name to Acme Corporation in October 2016. The company was founded in 1888 and is headquartered in Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania."

pattern1 = "\b(together with its subsidiaries,|Inc.|Inc.\s,|Corporation)\b"
pattern2 = "(together with its subsidiaries)|(Inc.)|(Inc.\s,)| (Corporation)"

first_idx = re.search(pattern1, test_string, 1).start()
term = res.search(pattern1, test_string, 1).group()
    
print(test_string[first_idx+len(term):].strip()
```

Have a lot more strings (like "Inc.", "Corp", "LLP", "plc") to search for. The first match is Corporation! The o/p should be:

```
produces and sells bauxite, alumina, and aluminum products in the United States, Spain, Australia, Brazil, Canada, and internationally. The company operates through three segments: Bauxite, Alumina, and Aluminum. It engages in bauxite mining operations; and processes bauxite into alumina and sells bauxite to customers who process it into industrial chemical products. The company is also involved in the aluminum smelting, casting, and rolling businesses; and the production of aluminum sheets primarily sold directly to customers in the packaging market for the production of aluminum cans. In addition, it owns hydro and coal generation assets that produce and sell electricity to the wholesale market to traders, large industrial consumers, distribution companies, and other generation companies. The company was formerly known as Acme Upstream Corporation and changed its name to Acme Corporation in October 2016. The company was founded in 1888 and is headquartered in Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania.
```

Read about lazy evaluation but cannot get a sense of how it applies here. It would be great if later references to Acme Corporation can also be stripped out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take care of the space after the `,` if you next test for a word boundary `\b`.

You have to incorporate the possibility that there is `Corporation` and/or `Inc.` before the `together with its subsidiaries,`

After the matched text, fetch the rest of the string and use that as the replacement in the `re.sub()`

```
test_string = "Acme Corporation Inc. , together with its subsidiaries, produces and sells bauxite, alumina, and aluminum products in the United States, Spain, Australia, Brazil, Canada, and internationally. The company operates through three segments: Bauxite, Alumina, and Aluminum. It engages in bauxite mining operations; and processes bauxite into alumina and sells bauxite to customers who process it into industrial chemical products. The company is also involved in the aluminum smelting, casting, and rolling businesses; and the production of aluminum sheets primarily sold directly to customers in the packaging market for the production of aluminum cans. In addition, it owns hydro and coal generation assets that produce and sell electricity to the wholesale market to traders, large industrial consumers, distribution companies, and other generation companies. The company was formerly known as Acme Upstream Corporation and changed its name to Acme Corporation in October 2016. The company was founded in 1888 and is headquartered in Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania."

pattern1 = r"^.*?\b((?:Corporation)?.*?(?:Inc.\s?,?)?.*?together with its subsidiaries,\s*|Inc.\s,|Inc.|Corporation)\b(.*)"

print(re.sub(pattern1, r"\2", test_string).strip())
```

---

**Edit**

If the number of possible prefixes is to much you should use a for loop

```
patterns = [r"together with its subsidiaries,\s*", r"Inc.\s,", r"Inc.", r"Corporation"]

result = test_string
for p in patterns:
    match = re.match(r"^.*?\b({})\b(.*)".format(p), test_string)
    if match:
        result = match.group(2)
        break

print(result)
```

Comment: thanks. but the op is not what it should be: "Inc. , together with its subsidiaries, produces and sells bauxite, alumina,..."

Comment: have you used my latest edit? I get `produces and sells bauxite......`

Comment: the first thing it tries to find is the string `together with its subsidiaries` that might contain `Corporation` and or `Inc.` before it. See https://regex101.com/r/jO8brf/1 for additional explanation of the symbols

Comment: great. can this be generalized for any number of strings?

Comment: the way a regex is matched you can also use a for loop and then you don't have the problem of possible prefixes that need to be added. see edit

Answer (score 0):

You could use the re.sub function. The re.sub function finds all the substrings inside a string that match a certain regex pattern and replaces them with another specified string.
If your desire is to collapse brand names, then the re.sub function can be used in the following fashion:

```
import re

string = "Acme is a really cool company because it sells good steel. Also, Acme happens to have a bunch of cool subsidiaries that Acme controls. Acme did pretty well on the last quarter."

new_string = re.sub("Acme", "", string)

print(new_string)
```

The previous code should print out the following:

is a really cool company because it sells good steel. Also,  happens to have a bunch of cool subsidiaries that  controls.  did pretty well on the last quarter.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't going to get it perfect. Looking for title case words will not do it perfectly, because starts of sentences are title case and some simple words (which you will likely not be able to enumerate exhaustively) will not be title case,

American Telephone and Telegragh, along with its subsidiaries, ....

Yesterday, Smith, Smith, and Wesson Corporation, added a new partner to...

But, you can match title case words leading up to Corporation or ", or its...".

```py
import re

replacement = re.sub(r"((?:[A-Z][a-z,] ?)+(Corporation|, (?:or|and|together with) its subsidiaries\b", "ANONYMIZEDNAME", input_text)
```

Comment: brackets weren't closed at the end. but the op is different. can you pls check?